# latex code suggestion

Tags: header-footer

I want to this footer "978-1-4673-6540-6/15/\$31.00~\copyright 2015 IEEE" to appear only in the first page of the article. Please give me a latex code. I tried few code but it is appearing in all pages. thank you.

Comment: im most classes (you really should say) `\thanks{978-1-4673-6540-6/15/\$31.00~\copyright 2015 IEEE}` in the title is the usual way

Comment: Welcome, i think the IEEE has some LaTeX templates out there? Why not using them?

Answer (score 2):

That's not your responsibility. IEEE places them automatically after publication. You don't do that. That's why it is not in the IEEE template.

Comment: thanks. but they have specifically asked us to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `IEEEtran`. You have to specify

```
\IEEEpubid{978-1-4673-6540-6/15/\$31.00~\copyright 2015 IEEE}
```

before `\maketitle` and then

```
\IEEEpubidadjcol
```

somewhere between paragraphs that fall in the second column of the first page.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for random text

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\IEEEpubid{978-1-4673-6540-6/15/\$31.00~\copyright 2015 IEEE}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[100]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[1-5]

\IEEEpubidadjcol % somewhere in the second column

\section{Some title}

\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]